# Blank display when I click submit button from the form

Tags: php, mysql

I create form which contain text fields and upload file(`register.php`), and I want to send data to `sendData.php` and redirect to `payment.php` in order user to make payment for document review.  I don't know where am wrong from `sendData.php`, I try to submit data from `register.php` to `sendData` and output is blank no error found, I try to check mysql error also no error found.

Page contain Form data

```
    <?php

    $errors = "";

    if(isset($_GET["error"])){

        if($_GET["error"] === "pwd"){


            $errors = '<div class="alert alert-danger col-md-3><span class="glyphicon glyphiocn-remove-circle"></span> Passowrd dismatch, please try again</div>';
        }

        if($_GET["error"] === "undefined"){


            $errors = '<div class="alert alert-danger col-md-3><span class="glyphicon glyphiocn-remove-circle"></span> File format dismatch, please try again</div>';

        }

        if($_GET["error"] === "found_file"){


            $errors = '<div class="alert alert-danger col-md-3><span class="glyphicon glyphiocn-remove-circle"></span> Document found error, please try again</div>';

        }



    }


    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>CentralAcademy: Register</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jumbtron.css">
        <link href="css/custom-file.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">

            body{  padding-top: 80px; }
          </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 breadcrumb">
    <h3 class="page-header">Payment</h3>
    <p><img src="images/images.png" class="img img-responsive" width="70" height="50" style="display: block; float: left; padding-right:10px;"/> (+255)755-555-555</p><br>


    <p><img src="images/airtelM.fw.png" class="img img-responsive"  width="70" height="50" style="display: block; float: left; padding-right:10px;"/> (+255)685-555-555</p><br>


    <p><img src="images/tigopesa.png" class="img img-responsive"  width="70" height="50" style="display: block; float: left; padding-right:10px;"/> (+255)655-555-555</p><br>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 breadcrumb">
    <?php print $errors; ?>
    <h3 class="page-header">Request for Document Review</h3>
    <h5><font color="#FF0000">***</font> Please fill all fields required</h5><br>

    <form action="sendData.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="Enter your FirstName" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '' ?>" class="form-control" required id="fname">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="sname" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['sname']) ? $_POST['sname'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter your LastName"  required id="sname">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="gender" type="radio" class="radio-inline" value="F" checked="CHECKED"  required/>Female&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" class="radio-inline" value="M"  required/>Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter your Email Address"  required id="email">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '' ?>" maxlength="13"  required id="phone" pattern="[\+]\d{3}\d{3}\d{6}">
    </div>
    </div>


      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <input type="radio" name="edlevel" value="bachelor" class="radio-inline" checked="CHECKED"  required/>Bachelor
    <input type="radio" name="edlevel" value="Post Graduate" class="radio-inline" />Post Grad 
    <input name="edlevel" type="radio" value="Masters" class="radio-inline"  />Masters
    <input name="edlevel" type="radio" value="PhD" class="radio-inline"  />PhD

    </div>
    </div>

       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="affi" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['affi']) ? $_POST['affi'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter organisation/College/University" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Enter your document title"  required>
    </div>
    </div> 

         <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 fileUpload">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file"/>
    </div>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose Your Password" required>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Your Password" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <button name="Register" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Register Now</button><br><br>


    <p>If you are already registered please click<a href="login.php"> here</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container marketing">

          <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->



          <?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>

        </div><!-- /.container -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

    //sendData.php

    <?php

    if(isset($_FILES['files']) && $_POST["password"] === $_POST["password2"]){

        session_start();
        require_once("includes/dbconnect.php"); 

        $fname = $_POST["fname"];
        $sname = $_POST["sname"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        $edlevel = $_POST["edlevel"];
        $affi = $_POST["affi"];


        //Keep all author data to session variable

        $_SESSION["fname"] = $fname;
        $_SESSION["sname"] = $sname;
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        $_SESSION["phone"] = $email;
        $_SESSION["passwprd"] = $password;
        $_SESSION["gender"] = $gender;
        $_SESSION["edlevel"] = $edlevel;
        $_SESSION["affi"] = $affi;

        $errors= array();

        $extensions = array("docx");  

            $file_name = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['files']['name'];

            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'];

            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'];

            $file_ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['files']['name'],strrpos($_FILES['files']['name'],'.')+1));

            if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions ) === true && $file_size < 2097152){

              $result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO temp VALUES(NULL,'$title',$email','$file_name',now())");

                if($result){

                 $desired_dir="AuthorReport";

            if(empty($errors)===true){ 

                if(is_dir($desired_dir)===false){

                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){

                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);

                }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();

                     rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
                }



                    header("location: payment.php");
                    exit();
                }

                    else{ header("location:register.php?error=found_file"); exit(); }


            }

    }

        else{ header("location:register.php?error=undefined"); exit(); }

    }

    else{ header("location:register.php?error=pwd"); exit(); }


    ?>
```

Comment: What does your apache error log say? (or whichever webserver you're using). More, have you tried turning on PHP's error reporting?

Comment: @lucas , ini_set('display_errors','1'); but no error found on the browser.

Comment: Your page gives me a few errors that are unrelated to this (trying sending headers after it's already sent data). And the form is submitting to sendData.php - is that this file, or is it an additional file? It's unclear.

Comment: Still problems , file is uploaded to the serve but temp table is empty.

Comment: check for the "real" error on the query then, you're not doing that.

Comment: Assuming that the file you're uploading has a .docx suffix, have you tried declaring the names of the columns your inserting into in your query? That could cause an error if the number of columns in the table doesn't match the number of values in the query.

Comment: $result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO temp(tempid,title,email,file,date) VALUES(NULL,'$title',$email','$file_name',now())");. No errors found, and temp table still empy

Comment: @ErickMongi You won't find Apache log in the **browser**. You need to look in the server!

Comment: Some of your if condition is without else part so if it go there it will give blank page result example : if $result is failed what will happen next think about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$email doesn't have start quote

```
$result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO temp VALUES(NULL,'$title',$email','$file_name',now())");
```

that's why you have the error.

and to be sure where are you entering these values exactly where you want use add also the column names in INSERT statement

```
$result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO temp 
(column_title, column_email, column_filename, thedate)
VALUES
('$title','$email','$file_name',NOW() )" );
```

Comment: one close parenthesis for ...values ()

Comment: Yes, sorry, just noticed it and updated the answer, but the quote for $email still missing.